# Hashing interview puzzle

Tags: interview-questions, swift, hashcode

I've stumbled upon [this](https://www.kevinhwong.com/articles/trello-s-hashing-interview-question) pretty old article about a hashing interview question, and here it is converted to Swift in a more generic way:

```
struct CustomHasher {

    /// An enum of the errors that may be thrown
    enum HashingError: Error {

        /// Thrown by the initializer
        /// when the alphabet contains repeating letters
        case invalidAlphabet

        /// Thrown by the initializer
        /// when the base is negative
        case invalidBase

        /// Thrown by the initializer
        /// when the offset is negative
        case invalidOffset

        /// Thrown by the hash(_:) function
        /// when the string provided uses illegal letters
        case outOfAlphabet(String)

        /// Thrown by the hash(_:) function
        /// when the string provided uses illegal letters
        case exceedsInt64

        /// Thrown by the reverseHash(_:) function
        /// when the string provided uses illegal letters
        case invalidHash
    }

    //Parameters
    private let base: Int64
    private let offset: Int64
    private let alphabet: String

    // An array that eases the access to the elements of the alphabet
    private let alphabetArray: [Character]

    private let stringLengthLimit: Int

    /// Convinience inializer
    /// - Parameters:
    ///     - alphabet: Must be a string of unique characters
    ///     - offset: A strictly positive Int64
    ///     - base: A strictly positive Int64
    /// - Throws:
    ///     - HashingError.outOfAlphabet(String)
    ///     - HashingError.invalidOffset
    init(alphabet: String, offset: Int64, base: Int64) throws {
        self.alphabet = alphabet
        self.alphabetArray = Array(alphabet)
        guard alphabetArray.count == Set(alphabet).count else {
            throw HashingError.invalidAlphabet
        }

        guard offset > 0 else {
            throw HashingError.invalidOffset
        }
        self.offset = offset

        guard base > 1 else {
            throw HashingError.invalidBase
        }
        self.base = base

        let b = Double(base)
        let c = Double(alphabetArray.count)
        let dOffset = Double(offset)
        let int64limit = Double(Int64.max)

        self.stringLengthLimit = ((0...).first {
            let power = pow(b, Double($0))
            let tail = $0 == 1 ? c * power : c * (power - 1) / (b - 1)
            let head = dOffset * power
            return head + tail > int64limit
            } ?? 0) - 1
    }

    /// Takes a string and converts it to a corresponding Int64
    /// - Parameters:
    ///     - str: The string to be hashed
    /// - Throws:
    ///     - HashingError.outOfAlphabet(String)
    ///     - HashingError.exceedsInt64
    func hash(_ str: String) throws -> Int64 {

        guard Array(str).count <= stringLengthLimit else {
            throw HashingError.exceedsInt64
        }
        var h: Int64  = offset
        for char in str {
            if let index: Int = alphabetArray.firstIndex(of: char) {
                h = h * base + Int64(index)
            } else {
                throw HashingError.outOfAlphabet(alphabet)
            }
        }
        return h
    }

    /// Reverses the hashing process
    /// - Parameters:
    ///     - str: The string to be hashed
    /// - Throws:
    ///     - HashingError.invalidHash
    func reverseHash(_ hash: Int64) throws -> String {

        guard hash >= offset else {
            throw HashingError.invalidHash
        }

        //Reached the end
        if hash == offset {
            return ""
        }

        let remainder: Int64 = hash % base
        let quotient: Int64 = (hash - remainder)/base

        let index: Int = Int(truncatingIfNeeded: remainder)
        guard index < alphabetArray.count else {
            throw HashingError.invalidHash
        }

        let char: Character = alphabetArray[index]
        return try reverseHash(quotient) + String(char)
    }
}
```

And here it is in use:

```
let base37 = try! CustomHasher(alphabet: "acdegilmnoprstuw",
                               offset: 7,
                               base: 37)

do {
    try base37.hash("leepadg")
} catch {
    print(error)
}

do {
    try base37.reverseHash(680131659347)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Feedback on all aspects of the code is welcome, such as (but not limited to):

- Should such a hasher throw? Or would it be more natural/idiomatic to return nil if it fails?
- Possible improvements (speed, clarity, especially the latter),
- Naming,
- Better comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### General stuff

Several explicit type annotations are not needed, such as in

```
var h: Int64  = offset

if let index: Int = alphabetArray.firstIndex(of: char)

let remainder: Int64 = hash % base
let quotient: Int64 = (hash - remainder)/base
```

#### Error handling

- In the initializer:

  Throwing an error for illegal parameters is fine, and allows to provide more details about the error than in a failable initializer. I only wonder why `offset` is required to be strictly positive. Is there any problem with allowing a zero offset?
- In the `hash` method:

  Again, throwing an error for bad input seems fine to me. However: Most hashing method accept arbitrary long input strings. If “overflow” is an error for this very special hasher then I would call just it `overflow` error instead of `exceedsInt64`.
- In the `reverseHash` method:

  This is again a special situation for this hasher, most hashing methods are designed in a way to make “dehashing” as computing intensive as possible. Here I would return `nil` instead of throwing an error if no matching source string is found, meaning “no result.”

#### The overflow checking

It is not immediately obvious how `self.stringLengthLimit` is calculated, this calls for an explaining comment. Also I am always a bit suspicious if integer and floating point arithmetic is mixed: A (64-bit) `Double` has a 53-bit significand precision and cannot store all 64-bit integers precisely.

*Anyway:* Detecting an overflow based on the string length alone cannot work in all cases. Here is an example: With

```
let base10 = CustomHasher(alphabet: "0123456789", offset: 9, base: 10)
```

the hash of "223372036854775807" fits into a 64-bit integer, but your program rejects that input string because its length exceeds `stringLengthLimit = 17`."223372036854775808" has the same length, but its hash calculation would overflow.

This shows that it is difficult to detect the overflow in advance. As an alternative, one could use the “overflow-reporting methods” for multiplication and addition. This is more code (and not nice to read) but detects overflow reliably:

```
guard let index = alphabetArray.firstIndex(of: char) else {
    throw HashingError.outOfAlphabet(alphabet)
}
guard
    case let r1 = h.multipliedReportingOverflow(by: base), !r1.overflow,
    case let r2 = r1.partialValue.addingReportingOverflow(Int64(index)), !r2.overflow
    else {
        throw HashingError.exceedsInt64
}
h = r2.partialValue
```

Of course these thoughts apply only to your special hasher. Usually one would accept arbitrary input, using (for example) `&+` and `&*` for addition and multiplication with automatic “wrap around.”

#### Simplifications

There is not very much to say, the code is written clearly. You store the given alphabet both as the original string and as an array of characters, but later use only the array.

The second line in

```
let remainder = hash % base
let quotient = (hash - remainder)/base
```

can be simplified to

```
let quotient = hash/base
```

You can also compute both quotient and remainder with a call to the BSD library function [`lldiv`](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/lldiv.3.html)

```
let remQuot = lldiv(hash, base)
```

but I doubt that it would be faster.

The recursion in the dehasher could be replaced by an iteration, that would allow to *append* to the result string, and only reverse once, instead of prepending characters to a string repeatedly:

```
var hash = hash
var result = ""
while hash > offset {
    let remainder = hash % base
    hash = hash / base
    let index = Int(truncatingIfNeeded: remainder)
    guard index < alphabetArray.count else {
        return nil
    }
    result.append(alphabetArray[index])
}
return hash < 0 ? nil : String(result.reversed())
```

But since the number of recursions/iterations is quite limited it probably won't make much of a difference, and you can choose what you find more natural.

#### Naming

`CustomHasher` does not tell anything about the type. I am not good in finding names, perhaps `TrelloHasher` if you want to emphasize where it comes from, or `MultAddHasher` ... naming is difficult (and subjective)!

Possible alternative method names would be

```
func hash(of s: String) {}
func string(for hash: Int64) {}
```

Comment: **General stuff** Type annotations were added purposefully to make the code clearer. It's a personal choice to make the reading experience seamless/effortless. Many errors occur out of misinferring the types. **Error handling)** With an offset equal to zero, the hash for an empty string would be the same as the one of the first character in the alphabet. **The overflow checking)** I'll have to adjust the `stringLengthLimit` by 1, and the formula for calculating it (the sum of a geometric series). The basic idea is checking that the max number generated by the `hash`function won't overflow.

Comment: (continuation) AFAIK `Int64.max`does fit into double precision: `Double.greatestFiniteMagnitude` is way bigger than `Int64.max`. and `Double(Int64.max) == 9223372036854775807` is true. I am avoiding *wrap around* since there might be overlaps (two -or more- words with the same hash). **Simplifications)** Thank you for the little `lldiv` jewel. [`quotientAndRemainder(dividingBy:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/int/2884924-quotientandremainder) was also possible.

Comment: @Carpsen90: You are right about offset=0. – Overflow checking based on the string length alone cannot work, as I tried to demonstrate with "223372036854775807" and "223372036854775808".  –  Double cannot represent all Int64 precisely, try `print(Double(Int64.max) == Double(Int64.max - 500))`.

Comment: You're right, there is a mathematical limit where `Double` wouldn't be precise enough. `Float80` seems to solve that (I'll have to check the docs).

Comment: @Carpsen90: Yes, but just note that Float80 is not portable: https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/FloatingPointTypes.swift.gyb#L1904: "Float80 is only available on non-Windows x86 targets."

Comment: As to the example of `"223372036854775808"`, the error message is not very helpful, since it warns about the possibility of overflowing with a string with 18 characters in the given example `base10` : The hash of a 18 character string with all `9`s in `base10` would be `9 999 999 999 999 999 999` which is is bigger than `Int64.max`. This is maybe too cautious, since some 18-character strings are still hashable using this hasher.

Comment: @Carpsen90: But that is exactly what I said: You cannot detect a possible overflow based only on the string length (but you can detect it during the calculation). Of course you can be overly cautious and reject strings whose hashes *could* be computed.

Comment: Anyway: A review is always subjective. I have expressed my concerns and recommendations. You don't have to agree with all points.